# Insert Add blocks in between view results only for S & XS devices

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I am using the Drupal 7 - view page with an attachment for displaying articles & featured articles, and i have some Add blocks displays in the right side bar in desktop view. When i move to mobile view( S & XS devices) i need to insert the adds in between view results.

Eg:

```
views-row-1
views-row-2
views-row-3
<Add Block>
views-row-4
views-row-5
views-row-6
<Add Block>
 -------
```

[image]

Note : Ad Blocks created using Doubleclick for Publishers (DFP) module.

Please give me some suggestions on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you be more specific please??. When you say "Add Block display", are you talking about a block display from a view?.

Comment: If I understood correctly he needs a field for advert in between fields in view. If this is correct you can use custom text field or even with views php module add global php field and put any kind of code there. Using the CSS you can hide adverts on desktop version. But if you are not using fields but nodes and you need advert in between results you can alter the template file or alter the view using hooks. Question needs more details in order to solve your problem.

Comment: @Daniela, I have added the pic for more details, And Ad blocks are created using Doubleclick for Publishers (DFP) drupal module which is assigned to the side bar in desktop view.

Comment: @Beyer, Thanks for your suggestions, If we load the add twice in the page it may be problem in ad impressions. May be i will try for the alter hooks, and i have updated the  question with some screenshot and Add block details.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view field template for your view page. It will looks like this:

sites/all/themes/your_theme/templates/views-view-fields--view-page.tpl.php

views-view-fields--view-page.tpl.php template file will contains this:

$field):

    if ($field->class == 'nothing') {

        ?>

```
    <div class="mobile"> //Remove this class if not mobile version

        <?php //this code is to add single addblock, but you can render the all adblock using foreach

        $blockObject = block_load('dfp', 'box1');
        $block = _block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($blockObject)));
        $output = drupal_render($block);

        print($output);
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php
}
if (!empty($field->separator)): ?>
    <?php print $field->separator; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php print $field->wrapper_prefix; ?>
<?php print $field->label_html; ?>
<?php print $field->content; ?>
<?php print $field->wrapper_suffix; ?>
```

Finally, configure the block, to not show it in your view page (path):

your_domain/admin/structure/block/manage/dfp/block_machine_name/configure

See the last section : Show block on specific pages